# unable to use fonts through CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have this CSS file for the free google font. The font and help was downloaded, but I am not able to use them as intended. How can I use them for displaying Bold or, Italic or, regular text?

my css: fonts.css

```
        /* anonymous-pro-regular - latin */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Anonymous Pro Regular'), local('AnonymousPro-Regular'),
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }

    /* anonymous-pro-italic - latin */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Anonymous Pro Italic'), local('AnonymousPro-Italic'),
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-italic.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }

    /* anonymous-pro-700 - latin */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      src: local('Anonymous Pro Bold'), local('AnonymousPro-Bold'),
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }

    /* anonymous-pro-700italic - latin */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 700;
      src: local('Anonymous Pro Bold Italic'), local('AnonymousPro-BoldItalic'),
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-700italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-700italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/anonymous-pro-v11-latin-700italic.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }


.myFontNormal {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro Regular';
}

.myFontBold {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro Bold';
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

When I try to use it in forms it does nothing. what am I missing?

e.g.:

```
<div id="main" class="myFontBold">
  <p>Default Emb.1234567890.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `.myFontBold { …; font-weight: 700; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different `font-family` names in the @font-face rules to make it work - you have `font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';` in all three! Add "Bold" and "Italic" to the second and third one.

Comment: No, you don’t _have to_ … think about it for a minute, when you go with a “classic” non-webfont like say, Times New Roman, you don’t have differently named versions of that for every weight style either … What you do, is you specify the font-weight as well, which OP simply neglected to do with their classes.

Comment: @04FS Just try it (with webfonts), and you'll see what I mean

Comment: I use the method I described regularly, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: So do I with what I described. And obviously it also worked for the OP.

Comment: That still doesn’t mean that you _have to_ do it this way, as you put it.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. That's kind of nit-picking, but okay, I changed that.

Comment: I don’t think that’s nit-picking - _“you have to”_ implies that this was the only way to handle this.